# How to generate a Penrose tessellation around a given tile?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, math-software, hamiltonian-path, tiling

Given a starting Penrose tile, I need to build a "spiraling" tessellation around it.

The following picture illustrates the request:

[image]

In this example, the starting tile is a "thin rhombus" (the pink one).

> **I need to write an algorithm which is able to generate the $n$ tiles (and whose output is, for instance a, SVG file), starting from any given tile, and with the possibility of coloring the tiles according to a given sequence of $n$ colors.**

Thanks for your help!

NOTE: This post is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906053/559615).

Comment: From a graph-point-of-view, you are traversing the dual-graph of the tiling, with the convention of taking the right-most turn each time.

Comment: @AlexR. The dual graph is the network of the centers of the tiles, right? In this case, the problem becomes how to predict the $n$-th center, right?

Comment: How is your penrose tiling stored?

Comment: So far I made a Xfig file (http://mcj.sourceforge.net), which can be easily transformed into a SVG file and viceversa, perhaps more common. In practice, for each tile I have 4 points. But I'm not sure it is the best way to store it.

Comment: Say, I would prefer not to store the underlying Penrose tiling, but to generate the next tile from first principles, a bit as i tried to depict in the figure above.

Comment: What I mean is, to store only the $n-1$ tiles before the new one.

Comment: I suppose that a recursive approach (i..e, start with a single large tile or a simple constellation of large tiles, and repeatedly replace large thin/fat rhombi by suitable constellations of smaller rhombi) is much easier zo implement fo ryour desired output.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for your suggestion. I will think about it!