# An integer sequence related to Penrose tessellation

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, number-theory, integers, tiling

Consider covering the plane by means of the classical Penrose tiles (i.e. the "fat" and "thin" rhombi) in a spiraling fashion, adding step by step a new tile around a given one, as introduced in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912213/559615).

At each step, we need one of the two tiles (and only one), as illustrated in the following picture:

[image]

- The starting tile is the pink one.
- The segments connecting the centers of the tiles represent the consecutive steps of the spiral walk around the starting tile.
- The numbers inside the tiles (1, fat rhombus; $\color{red} 0$, thin rhombus), highlight the alternation of the two kinds of tiles as a function of the walk step.

Displaying these numbers in a sequence, we find:

$s(n)=1$,$1$,$1$,$1$,$\color{red}0$,$1$,$1$,$\color{red}0$,$1$,$\color{red}0$,$\color{red}0$,$1$,$\color{red}0$,$\color{red}0$,$1$,$1\ldots$

My question is:

> **Is there a closed formula for $s(n)$?**

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I checked the OEIS but the sequence is unknown. The sequence should be added to the OEIS.

Comment: @user25406 Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: For what it's worth, it's a bit more natural to look at paths that jump between tiles respecting a single edge orientation. For example, starting from the red tile, if you choose to make your first step as you've shown, to the 1 tile, then the next step should actually be to the 0 tile (their edges are *parallel*). These kinds of paths are sometimes called de-Bruijn worms (or sometimes Conway Worms). These are bit more boring since tile types are regular here, but then interesting questions can be asked about what the path looks like

Comment: (Here's a picture to help: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Remy_Mosseri/publication/1797200/figure/fig6/AS:668411684204571@1536373172997/A-patch-of-octagonal-4-2-tiling-Some-worms-de-Bruijn-lines-are-represented-There_Q320.jpg)

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks (again) for your interesting observation. Just, I wonder if with such "worms" we can actually cover the whole plane with a single path: For instance, it seems to me that if we move away from the red tile with the rule of the parallel edge, then the path goes quickly very far from the central tile, with no chance to cover the area immediately around it, right?

Comment: However, $s(n)$ looks to me a base-$2$ representation of the expansion of some number. I wonder which number...

Answer (score 1):

There are two other sequences relevant to this tiling. In both cases it can be treated like a $1$-dimensional (Elementary) cellular automaton. Firstly, take all units associated by edge with a particular unit and take the result modulo $2$.

Secondly to draw a line radially though it from any point and at any given angle and take the bit value of the units intersected.

My guess is that you could yield a generative formula for determining the next state.

Also, there are typically “rules” regarding the orientation of the tiles (using markings on them to exclude certain orientations and permutations), these add a non-binary aspect to the continuation of the sequence. It might be a good idea to make an assessment of those before simply collecting the bit value of each cell.